# How to create dynamic grid view in angular by using ant design?

Tags: angular, grid, ng-zorro-antd

I have one child component, which has an NZ-card design view like this,
[image]

in the parent component, I need to call this child component to form a dynamic grid view. Also I need to pass like card title, Images, description etc.. data from parent to child component. Please help, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you get your list of cards using an API. You will end up with an `Observable<CardData>` where `CardData` is a type which contains your title, image url, description etc...

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: '<your-card *ngFor="let card of cards | async" [data]="card"></your-card>'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  cards$: Oservable<CardData>;
}
```

Then you can use CSS grids.